# Trigonometric definite integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Integrate $$\int_{-1}^{3/2}|x\sin(\pi x)| dx$$
I don't know how to handle the modulus and also have no idea how to Integrate if there was no modulus, integration by parts isn't working, may be King's property can work but I don't know what to do with modulus.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-1}^{3/2}|x\sin(\pi x)| dx = \int_{-\pi}^{1.5\pi} |z\sin z|dz = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}z\sin z dz - \int_{\pi}^{1.5\pi}z\sin z dz$$

In the firs equality, I substituted $z = \pi x$ and in the second equality I made use of the fact that $z\sin z$ is positive in $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and negative in $\pi$ to $1.5\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

As $(-x)\sin(-\pi x)=x\sin(\pi x)$

$$\int_{-1}^{3/2}|x\sin\pi x|dx=2\int_0^1x\sin\pi x\ dx+\int_1^{3/2}x\sin\pi x\ dx$$

Now integrate by parts  $$\int x\sin(\pi x)dx=x\int\sin(\pi x)dx-\int\left(\dfrac{dx}{dx}\cdot\int\sin(\pi x)dx\right)dx$$