# Why is it called 'King's Property of Integration'?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, math-history

Recently I learned about "King's Property" or "King's Rule" and I was wondering about its etymology? I understand that it's a basic change of variables but it has a name for a reason. I've been unable to find this reason online. I speculate that the person who first encountered it had the popular surname King.

In case terminology is different elsewhere, here's what I'm talking about:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$

Comment: The person who discovered this probably wanted to overly praise their discovery.

Comment: This might be better-suited to hsm.se.

Comment: I don't like this way of presenting that formula. It is much better to showcase it on a symmetric interval; $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx =\int_{-a}^a f(-x)\, dx.$$ If you present it like this, there is no need for baroque names, and what is going on is much clearer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answers have shown that this is a HSM question.

Comment: @J.G. Apologies, I wasn't aware of the HSM subsite.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro While that special case implies the general one, it'd be a shame to have to shift like that every time we want to exploit it to prove e.g. $\int_0^1\frac{f(x)dx}{f(x)+f(1-x)}=\tfrac12$.

Answer (score 10):

I have never heard this referred to as "King's Property" or "King's Rule".  And there is almost nothing (except this thread) in Google.  There is this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UtET8XU1wk), maybe your answer is there. (Video can be viewed only by paid students)  Maybe the term "King's Property" is unique to that video.

> [image: search image]

The video is from an educational company (?) called Nucleon, located in Rajasthan, in northern India.  "Rajasthan" means "Land of Kings".

---

As pointed out in a comment, the "King's Property" has been mentioned in math.se before.  The oldest one seems to be [Trigonometric definite integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363675/trigonometric-definite-integration) .  That post is from July, 2017.  The post is by Tarun Raj Latiyan.  Wouldn't it be interesting if Tarun is from India and learned this terminology from the Nucleon video?

Comment: I never saw it called by any name except on another Q on this site this year.

Comment: its referred to as king's property at most after school tution institutes

Comment: @DankCoder Most... in India probably

Answer (score 2):

If you are a JEE Aspirant (of India) then you might have heard of this person VK Bansal, the man behind for what now Kota is known for. He was the owner of Bansal Classes and used to teach mathematics himself. He used to assign names to the properties and the names you see now King's, Queen's, Jack's Rule are nothing but unofficial names designed by him.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the Queen's & Jack's rules are, or anywhere we can find more of Bansal's terminology? Aside from the question of whether such results "deserve" these names or he "deserves" to name them, anything he gave such names is likely worth knowing of, regardless of name.

Comment: @J.G. It seems the "Queen's Rule" refers to $$\int_0^{2a}f(x)\,\text{d}x=\begin{cases}2\int_0^af(x)\,\text{d}x\quad\text{if }f(2a-x)=f(x)\\\quad\quad0\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\text{if }f(2a-x)=-f(x)\end{cases},$$ while "Jack's Rule" refers to a property for a periodic function $f(x)$ where $$\int_0^{nT}f(x)\,dx=n\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx.$$ All in all, I believe these are just fancy names given to fundamental properties of definite integrals.

Comment: @TiagoAndré Thank you.