Integrating $\int_{-1}^1 \arctan(x)\arcsin(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$
I am having trouble with the following challenge problem from the series and integrals section of a book I have:
$$\int_{-1}^1 \arctan(x)\arcsin(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$
My book gives the following hint: $$\arctan(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}\, \mathrm{d}y$$
I have tried to rewrite this as geometry series with ratio $x^2y^2$ and try to integrate with respects to $x$ that way, but it results in an integral of $\sin(x)^{2n+1}$, resulting in a series involving partial products of a Wallace product-like product that seems to be an ineffective approach. Does anyone know of another approach keeping with this approach?

Hint: substitute $x=\sin u$, replace $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}u$ with $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}u$, then use King's rule.

Note "King's Rule" seems to be terminology known only in India ... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3952365/442

\begin{align}J&=\int_{-1}^1 \arctan(x)\arcsin(x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^1\arctan(x)\arcsin(x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\overset{u=\arcsin x}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}u\arctan(\sin u)\cos udu\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=2\Big[u\arctan(\sin u)\sin u\Big]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\\
&2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin u\left(\arctan(\sin u)+\frac{u\cos u}{1+\sin^2u}\right)du\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4-2\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan(\sin u)\sin udu}_{=J_1}-2\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{u\sin u\cos u}{1+\sin^2u}du}_{=J_2}\\
J_1&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\Big[\arctan(\sin u)\cos u\Big]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2u}du\\
&=\Big[\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\tan u\right)-u\Big]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\boxed{\frac{\pi}2\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\\
J_2&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac12\Big[u\ln(1+\sin^2u)\Big]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1+\sin^2u)du\\
&=\frac\pi4\ln 2-\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1+\sin^2u)du}_{z=\cot u}\\
&=\frac\pi4\ln 2-\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{1+z^2})}{1+z^2}dz\\
&=\frac\pi4\ln 2+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+z^2)}{1+z^2}dz}_{=J_3}-\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(2+z^2)}{1+z^2}dz}_{=J_4}\\
J_3&\overset{w=\tan z}=-2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos w)dw=\boxed{\pi\ln 2}\\
&a\in [0,1],F(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+a^2x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
F^\prime(a)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{2ax^2}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2x^2)}dx\\
&=\left[\frac{2a\arctan x}{a^2-1}-\frac{a\arctan(ax)}{a^2-1}\right]_0^\infty=\frac{\pi}{1+a}\\
F(a)&=\int_0^a\frac{\pi}{1+t}dt=\pi\ln(1+a)\\
J_4&=\ln2\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+z^2}dz+F\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\boxed{\frac{\pi\ln 2}2+\pi\ln\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
J_2&=\boxed{\frac{\pi\ln 2}2-\frac{\pi\ln\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)}2}\\
&\boxed{J=\frac{\pi^2}4-\pi\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)-\pi\ln 2+\pi\ln\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)}
\end{align}
NB:
\begin{align}\boxed{J=\frac{\pi^2}4-\pi\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)-\frac{3\pi\ln 2}{2}+\pi\ln\left(1+{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\end{align}

Hint/Sketch: So, using your series expansion, we would have
$$\newcommand{\II}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\para}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\br}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
 \frac{x}{1+x^2y^2} 
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n+1} y^{2n}
$$
and, assuming interchanging the integral and sum are valid,
$$
\II = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_{-1}^1   \int_0^1 x^{2n+1} y^{2n}
  \, \arcsin x \, \dd x \, \dd y
$$
We can separate into $x,y$ integrals as so:
$$
\II = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \br{ \int_{-1}^1  y^{2n} \, \dd y } \br{ \int_0^1 x^{2n+1}
  \, \arcsin x \, \dd x }
$$
The former integral is trivial. The integral of the latter is found via a reduction formula of sorts: for $m \ne -1$,
$$
\int_0^1 x^m \arcsin x \, \dd x
=
\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} \arcsin x \bigg|_0^1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{m+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, \dd x
$$
(easily justified with integration by parts). With the substitution $u=1-x^2$, you can express the latter in terms of the beta function and work from there.

Carrying out the above steps, I arrive at the following series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(\pi-B(\frac{1}{2}, n+\frac{3}{2}))}{2(n+1)(2n+1)}$$ Are there any special beta function properties that might make this computable?

Dqrksun: Proofread your text!  I figured out \II and \dd, but what's \br?

That one was actually my fault, I had some newcommands that were in a block I later deleted, because I saw that the step in the process was superfluous, but I didn't realize I had killed off my newcommands (or that they had tried to fix that).

Starting from @PrincessEev's answer
$$I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \int_{-1}^1  y^{2n} \, d y  \int_0^1 x^{2n+1}\, \arcsin( x) \,  dx$$ the latter antiderivative is given in terms of a Gaussian hypergeometric function and
$$\int_0^1 x^{2n+1}\, \arcsin( x) \,  dx=\frac 1{4(n+1)}\Bigg(\pi-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)} \Bigg)$$
So
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2 (n+1) (2 n+1)}\Bigg(\pi-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)} \Bigg)$$
$$S_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,\pi}{2 (n+1) (2 n+1)}=\frac{ \pi}{2}  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\log (2)\right)$$
$$S_2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,\sqrt{\pi }}{2 (n+1) (2 n+1)}\frac{ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)}=\frac{\pi}{4}   \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;2,2;-1\right)$$
$$S_2=\pi  \left(\sqrt{2}-1+\log (2)-\sinh^{-1}(1)\right)$$
$$I=S_1-S_2=\pi\Big(1+\frac \pi 4 +\sinh ^{-1}(1)-\frac 32 \log(2)-\sqrt 2  \Big)$$

I'm confused as to how you evaluated the hypergeometric function to the expression you got for $S_2$. By what means did you simplify it?

I'm sorry, what is the edit?

@Lysi-2. Some of them are pretty well known
